# Firebase Crash Reporting console - How to use open/closed filter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I have an Android app that has incorporated Firebase crash reporting.

When I view the crashes in the console, there's a filter option for the "clusters". It's set to 'open' in the image below.[image]

When set to open, I see all the clusters. When set to closed, I don't see any clusters whatsoever. When and how can a cluster become closed? What does it mean for a cluster to be open or closed? I'm assuming it's a means of marking the issue resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Open/Closed feature is a way for you the developer to mark a particular issue as "open" or "closed." In other words it allows you to mark a crash as fixed so that you can filter out issues that you have already addressed.

To mark a cluster as closed, click the three dots on the far right of the row that appear when hovering over the row, then click "close cluster."

[image: Menu button on right side of row while hovering]

Comment: Aha! There's what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you know what happens if you close an issue but you get more reports on it? Will it reopen/will you get the new alert notifications or email? Or do you just risk hiding an error forever?

Comment: I do not know. I haven't had a chance to see that flow in action yet. I would assume it is similar to Fabric, which re-opens issues if a new version is released that has the same crash.

Comment: @Gober I closed all clusters and the errors kept being incremented without re-opening the relevant cluster. I have not found how to re-open the cluster...

Comment: @Gober - Correction: you can re-open the closed clusters by clicking on the Open drop-down menu in the cluster area and choosing "Closed". This will re-open the closed clusters. duh....(but this was not so obvious until I found it...)

Comment: I have tested this too. If you close a cluster and release a new version you get a special email if the error happens again saying: "Your app recently experienced errors that resemble closed error clusters (from an older version of your app). These error clusters have been reopened, with details below.". So it is safe to close clusters and all is good